# How to populate zeitgeist with firefox favorites and visited pages

Tags: 14.04, firefox, zeitgeist

Pretty straightforward question here. How to populate zeitgeist with the pages visited & favs from Firefox?

I remember that there was a package/extension that provided that in the past, but I cannot find any reference to it anymore. I am running 14.04 here.

As I side question, if someone happen to know a way of populate zeitgeist with musics listened on noise, I would appreciate.

Best,

Comment: Asuming you are using Unity, if you type "firefox:" in the launcher your bookmarks should appear.

Comment: Thanks for the commentary, but I want to access this information through synapse launcher. Do you have any idea how is it possible?